# WPF Recursive User Control

Tags: c#, wpf, recursion, user-controls

I have created a User Control that is designed to simplify the use of a recursive popup dialog system in which a popup dialog can have a popup dialog open within it.

Here is the User Control's XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SEA.WPF.View.Controls.DialogPresenter"
             Name="This"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SEA.WPF.View.Controls"
             xmlns:ts="clr-namespace:SEA.WPF.View.TemplateSelectors"
             xmlns:c="clr-namespace:SEA.WPF.View.DataConverters"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <c:InstanceToVisibilityConverter x:Key="InstanceToVisibilityConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid Visibility="{Binding Dialog, Converter={StaticResource InstanceToVisibilityConverter}}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=Dialog, ElementName=This}"
                            ContentTemplateSelector="{Binding Path=DialogTemplateSelector, ElementName=This}" />
        </Border>
        <ContentControl Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Content="{Binding Path=Dialog.Dialog, ElementName=This}">
            <ContentControl.ContentTemplateSelector>
                <ts:InstanceOnlyTemplateSelector>
                    <ts:InstanceOnlyTemplateSelector.Template>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <local:DialogPresenter Dialog="{Binding Path=Dialog.Dialog, ElementName=This}"
                                                   DialogTemplateSelector="{Binding Path=DialogTemplateSelector, ElementName=This}" /> 
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ts:InstanceOnlyTemplateSelector.Template>
                </ts:InstanceOnlyTemplateSelector>
            </ContentControl.ContentTemplateSelector>
        </ContentControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Here is `InstanceOnlyTemplateSelector`:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace SEA.WPF.View.TemplateSelectors
{
    public class InstanceOnlyTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public DataTemplate Template
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
            return item == null ? null : Template;
        }
    }
}
```

The `InstaceOnlyTemplateSelector` is there so that the recursive `DialogPresenter` is only rendered when the child dialog is not `null` (thus avoiding a Stack Overflow cause by the recursive binding).

The problem is, that when the child dialog changes from `null` to something else then the recursive `DialogPresenter` does not render like it's parent. I have tried replacing the `DialogPresenter` with a `Grid` with `Background` equal to `Brushes.Black` and that made the whole screen black (as expected).

Why is the recursive instance of the `DialogPresenter` not rendering as expected?

Comment: I also tried using RelativeSource instead of ElementName in my bindings but that didn't work either.

Comment: Actually by popups I mean dialogs but since I'm using MVVM they aren't in separate windows, they are layered instead. As a result, I need multiple layers. For example, the first layer would be used to "Add A New XXX" and the second would be for a validation message relating to the addition of a new XXX.